# Probability Distributions and Probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Suppose $X \sim N(3, 4)$, and let $Y = X^2$. Find $\Pr(Y ≥ 12)$.

What does $Y$ mean?

Comment: As a random variable Y takes the squared values of X. It is a function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Maybe you should ask more precisely..

Answer (score 2):

$Y$ means just what you said it means: It's the square of $X$, i.e. $Y=X^2$.  Notice that the event that $Y\ge 12$ is the same as the event $\left[X\ge\sqrt{12}\text{ or }X\le-\sqrt{12}\right]$, so the probability that $Y\ge 12$ is the same as the probability of the latter event.

**PS:** Because of some confusion appearing from comments below, I am adding some more details here.  The probability is
$$
\Pr\left( \frac{X-3}{2} \ge \frac{\sqrt{12}-3}2 \right) + \Pr\left( \frac{X-3}{2} \le \frac{-\sqrt{12}-3}2 \right)
$$
$$
= 1-\Phi\left( \frac{\sqrt{12}-3}2 \right) + \Phi\left(\frac{-\sqrt{12}-3}{2}\right) 
$$
$$
\approx 1-0.59175 + 0.00061 = 0.40886
$$

Comment: you may note $X$ is not standardnormal, so $F(x)=\Phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})$ where $\Phi$ is the usual standardnormal cdf.

Comment: @emcor : True, but that didn't seem to be where the problem was.

Comment: Normal distribution has symmetry, so $P(\cdot)=2\Phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})$.

Comment: @emcor : No, it's not.  That would be correct if $\mu$ were halfway between $\pm12$.  But $3$ is not halfway between $\pm12$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: . . . or more precisely, it would be right of the $x$ above refer to $-\sqrt{12}$, not $+\sqrt{12}$, and $\mu$ were $0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

$Y$ is a transformation of $X$, and $Y/\sigma^2$ is [Noncentral Chisquare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution) distributed, where $\lambda=\mu^2/\sigma^2=3^2/4=2.25$, $\,\,k=1$.

Its [CDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) $F^{\lambda,k}_{Y/\sigma^2}(x)$ is a bit complicated, you may use [MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/stats/ncx2cdf.html) for it.

Then:

$P(Y\geq12)=P(Y/\sigma^2\geq12/\sigma^2)=1-F^{\lambda,k}_{Y/\sigma^2}(12/\sigma^2)\approx 1-0.591136=0.408864$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Doesn't $N$ imply that it **is** distributed normally?

Comment: That is why I rescaled it now ;) You may note $X=4Z+3, Z\sim N(0,1).$

Comment: You have $((X-3)/4)^2\sim\chi^2_1$, but I don't know the meaning of the notation $\chi^2_1((X-3)/4)$.  In fact $X/4$ has a noncentral chi-square distribution.  But I don't think that helps here.  You just need $\Pr(X\ge\sqrt{12})+\Pr(X\le-\sqrt{12})$ $=\Pr\left(\dfrac{X-3}{2}\ge\dfrac{\sqrt{12}-3}{2}\right) + \Pr\left(\dfrac{X-3}{2}\le\dfrac{\sqrt{12}-3}{2}\right)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Normally $N(3,4)$ means $\sigma^2=4$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I posted another edit so I get the same probability finally..